# Differentiation problem probably using increasing or decreasing property of differentiation

Tags: implicit-differentiation

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be twice differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{p\}$, for some $p$ belonging to $\mathbb{R}$. If $f'(x)<0<f''(x)$ on $x <p$ and $f'(x) >0 >f''(x)$ on $x>p$, then $f$ is not differentiable at $p$.

Comment: The implicit differentiation tag seems misplaced?

Comment: Sir, I was aware that the tag is wrong but when I was typing differentiation it is the only tag which appeared and my apologies for tagging it wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous at $p$ then it must have a strict minimum at $p$.

If $f$ is differentiable at $p$ then it must be continuous at $p$ and hence $f'(p) = 0$. Since $f''(x) < 0 $ for $x >p$ we must have $f'(x) <0$ for $x >p$, a contradiction.

Comment: How can you conclude f'(p)=0

Comment: I got it. Thanks for the solution.